# OpenGL ati mobility radeon 3400 with genymotion

Tags: opengl, intellij-idea, genymotion, ati

How can i fix this problem? have ati mobility radeon 3400 with openGL 3.2 support.

http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-3000/hd-3400/Pages/hd-3400-specs.aspx

When i try genymotion (for example) it get me error "Unable to start Genymotion virtual device. Unable to initialize openGL renderer library. Check if your video card supports OpenGl 2.0. If no, then Genymotion virtual device can not start. If yes, maybe you should update your video drivers."

My video driver is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem and so I eh read the fault can come from Mesa. Of course I'm assuming you are using Linux. 're looking aver that I have the version 8 test # glxinfo |. grep Mesa, not sure if that is the solution update table through 10 I'm still proving greetings